The HTML data frame in R in sendmailR package body mail
I want to send a dataframe from R to an email address, but I want to show it with kableextra package with scroll box because it is a big dataframe. Is this possible? I can send the dataframe as an Excel file, but I wonder if there is a way to send it in kbl() HTML format.
library(dplyr)
library(sendmailR)
set.seed(123)

random_df <- tibble(
  column1 = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE),     
  column2 = runif(10, min = 0, max = 1),          
  column3 = sample(LETTERS, 10, replace = TRUE),   
  column4 = rnorm(10, mean = 50, sd = 10)        
)


sendmailR::sendmail(from="mail address",
         to="mail address",
         subject="this is a test",
         msg=random_df%>%
           kableExtra::kbl()%>%
           kable_styling(),
         control=mailControl)



